# Auditing Exchange mailbox

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

Is it possible in Exchange 2010 to enable auditing for a mailbox to log when emails are deleted and by whom?

If not, can anyone recommend third party software to do this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need third party software, you can enable auditing with cmdlets in Exchange Management Shell: `Set-Mailbox -Identity "Ben Smith" -AuditEnabled $true` enables auditing for Ben Smith's mailbox. See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff461937.aspx

For more information about Mailbox Audit Logging see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff459237.aspx

Comment: where is the logging done, in the event viewer?

Comment: "Log entries are stored in the Audits subfolder of the audited mailbox Recoverable Items folder." (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff459237.aspx#Mail)